# future continuous or present continuous in that case

Tags: future-constructions

. Before she is working in  June and  July .She found a job as "auxiliaire de vie" in Lyon where she **will be helping** old people .

Shall I use is helping instead of will be helping. I don't think so as her job has not begun and it is not an arrangment

Comment: *in* June and *where* she will be helping

Comment: You need to improve the grammar and punctuation in the rest of the sentence so we can understand the meaning